# Custom rewrite_rules - only pass numbers and not alphabetic characters

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, regex, query-variable

I'm trying to add a rewrite rule to pass a var to a custom page template.

For some weird reason it only excepts numbers in the variables, when I type in characters other then number it directs to `404`.

#### For example

This works: `http://example.com/reco/9080`

But this doesn't: `http://example.com/reco/abcd` (redirects to `404`)

This is my code:

```
function add_rewrite_rules($wp_rewrite) {
        add_rewrite_rule('reco/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php/reco/?b=$1', 'top');
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'add_rewrite_rules');


function query_vars($public_query_vars) {
    $public_query_vars[] = "b";
    return $public_query_vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'query_vars');
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `index.php/reco/?b=$1`, try this:

```
"$wp_rewrite->index?pagename=reco&b=" . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 1 )
```

You should also append a `$` to your `reco/([^/]*)/?` regex to ensure the rule only matches the entire path, and not just the beginning.

Then flush your rules afterwards (just re-save your permalink settings in admin).

**Update:** Try using the `page_rewrite_rules` filter instead, and use `get_query_var( 'b' )`:

```
function wpse_139259_page_rules( $rules ) {
    return array(
        'reco/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=reco&b=$matches[1]',
    ) + $rules;
}

add_filter( 'page_rewrite_rules', 'wpse_139259_page_rules' );
```

Comment: Not working :( when i print out the GET array this is what i get: 
  Array
(
    [pagename] => reco
    [b] => $matches[1]
)
It doesnt parse the $matches[1] var into a value

Comment: See revised answer :)

Comment: Thanks but still no go... now nothing gets passed... :±(

Comment: Did you flush your rules again?

Comment: I just checked myself & works ok for me.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up solving it with a class i found online by Kyle E Gentile, I cant post an answer yet (8 hours restriction) but i'll post it when it expires. thanks anyway Medic!